# Function to return a list - issue with filtering the output

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to output only articles if `authorsId = authorId`.

Beside that the whole function works exactly as I want, here it is:

The general idea is to limit access to only own articles.

So, my question is: how do I limit the results to show only articles written by the owner of the page we are on (`authorsId = authorId`).

```js
function ArticlesListReturn(returned) {
    xml = returned.documentElement;
    var rel = document.getElementById('related_category_articles');
    rel.options.length = 0;
    var status = getXMLData('status');
    var title = '';
    var id = '';
    var authorid = '';


    if (status == 0) {
      alert("%%LNG_jsArticleListError%%" + errormsg);
    } else {
      var authorid = document.getElementById("authorid").value; // Serge

      //    authorsid = getNextXMLData('authors',x);
      for (var x = 0; x < xml.getElementsByTagName('titles').length; x++) {


        title = getNextXMLData('titles', x);
        id = getNextXMLData('ids', x);
        authorsid = getNextXMLData('authors', x);

        alert(authorsid) // authors of each article - it returns the proper values
        alert(authorid) // author of the page we are on - it returns the proper value

        var count = 0;

        rel.options[x] = new Option(title, id, authorid); // lign that returns results

        title = '';
        id = '';
        authorid = '';

      }
}
```

Comment: You still have a loose `rel.options`

Comment: @mplungjan I updated. As for your question about getNextXMLData, it has to do with something else (once the list is produced), I think is it irrelevant to the question. rel.options (not sure to understand).

Comment: `rel.options <<< needs to go - next line is 
        var count = 0;`

Comment: I assume the answer is `if (authorid == authorsid) rel.options[x] = new Option(title, id, authorid);`

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, you are right, about rel.options (corrected). As for your answer, it returns an empty list. I am weak in understanding if and for each... I think the issue here it to have the equivalence check for each article.

Comment: So now we need examples of proper values and their type. Instead of alerting use console.log(authorid, authorsid)

Comment: @mplungjan - I Tried also the solution from fiprojects, it returns also an empty list. The 'ids' are numbers (with alert, It returns once only the id ex.(2) of the owner of the page, and for each article, ids of each ex. (2,5,39,64, etc.). Got the point about console,log)

Comment: Try to put debugger; statement into your code and check how it work step-by-step. It will make problem more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is when you try performing a conditional statement (if/then/else) that you are comparing a number to a string (or a string to a number). This is like comparing if (1 == "1" ) for example (note the double quotes is only on one side because the left would be numeric, the right side of the equation would be a string).

I added a test which should force both values to be strings, then compares them. If it still gives you problems, make sure there are no spaces/tabs added to one variable, but missing in the other variable.

Also, I changed your "alert" to output to the console (CTRL+SHIFT+J if you are using firefox). The problem using alert is sometimes remote data is not available when needed but your alert button creates a pause while the data is being read. So... if you use alert, your code works, then you remove alert, your code could reveal new errors (since remote data was not served on time). It may not be an issue now, but could be an issue for you going forward.

Best of luck!

```
function ArticlesListReturn(returned) {
    xml = returned.documentElement;
    var rel = document.getElementById('related_category_articles');
    rel.options.length = 0;
    var status = getXMLData('status');
    var title = '';
    var id = '';
    var authorid = '';


    if (status == 0) {
      alert("%%LNG_jsArticleListError%%" + errormsg);
    } else {
      var authorid = document.getElementById("authorid").value; // Serge

      //    authorsid = getNextXMLData('authors',x);
      for (var x = 0; x < xml.getElementsByTagName('titles').length; x++) {


        title = getNextXMLData('titles', x);
        id = getNextXMLData('ids', x);
        authorsid = getNextXMLData('authors', x);

        console.log("authorsid = "+authorsid); // authors of each article - it returns the proper values
        console.log("authorid = "+authorid); // author of the page we are on - it returns the proper value


if( authorsid.toString() == authorid.toString() )
{

        rel.options
        var count = 0;
console.log( authorsid.toString()+" equals "+authorid.toString() );
        rel.options[rel.options.length] = new Option(title, id, authorid); // lign that returns results

}    
else
{
    console.log( authorsid.toString()+" NOT equals "+authorid.toString() );
}


        title = '';
        id = '';
        authorid = '';

      }
```

*Did you check the console for messages? Did it correctly show authorid and authorsid?*

I have edited the script and made a couple of additions...

1. The console will tell you if the conditional check worked or not (meaning you will get a message for each record). See the "if/else" and the extra "console.log" parts I added?
2. rel.options[x] changed to equal rel.options[rel.options.length]. I am curious on why you set rel.options.length=0 when I would instead have done rel.options=new Array();

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Your solution returns an empty list. I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes I did, it returns once both (authorid and authorsid) and for the rest, it returnes authorsid with a blank for  authorid. And the overall result is again a blank list. This is with your latest changes.

So it looks like the if statement does not apply to each article.

Comment: if( authorsid.toString() ==  autorid) <-- this little change made fjprojects solution work! Thanks all!